# Why my body's background color leaks out of its boundaries?

Tags: css, background-color, document-body

In [this page](http://result.dabblet.com/gist/3869589/9df1c4de67ae227aecfb57ee16ff9eaade788727) I have a 200x200 body with a blue background.

However the background is applied to the whole window?

Why is this so?

Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/3869589/9df1c4de67ae227aecfb57ee16ff9eaade788727

Browser's I've tested against: FF 16 and Chrome 22.

Comment: Dunno, applying a background to the html tag 'fixes' it though.

Comment: You can use a `div` for you block. Body it the whole window.

Comment: +1 for a good question. The answer is: Because a long time ago the body was the only thing that could get a background, and there was confusion about padding and scrolling and backgrounds on it versus the html element. Now that modern browsers allow you to set separate CSS attributes for both `<html>` and `<body>`, there is still some convenient legacy behavior that says "If the body has certain attributes and the HTML doesn't have them set, put them on HTML." _(Not written as an answer because I have no sources or details to back this up.)_

Answer (score 2):

I would put the 200x200 blue box inside it's own  tag inside the body.

```
<style> .blue-box{ width:200px; height:200px; background:blue; } </style>

<body>
    <div class="blue-box"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, the body tag can actually be used as a regular block level element so it's not essential.

Comment: I changed the verbiage to I instead of you :)

Comment: I am not asking how I can avoid it, I want to know why the background is applied to the `<html>` element rather than the `<body>`.